# Recursion in Python with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tail-recursion

So I'm probably just being dumb here and don't understand a basic mechanic of python, but I'm trying to go through and crawl through a webpage, and then get a new link and continue on recursively. Here's a rough breakdown:

```
def go_to_next_page(soup, data, curr_link):
    print "Curr Link: " + curr_link 
    # gather information and append to data
    new_link = ""  # unless I find link with Beautiful Soup

    if new_link is not "":
        print "Next Link: " + new_link
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(mechanize.urlopen(new_link))
        data = go_to_next_page(new_soup, data, new_link)
    return data
```

But it's not creating a new Soup when it enters the second time through, and then has no data to gather.

Is this a Beautiful Soup issue, or am I doing recursion in Python wrong

Answer (score 1):

You do not get the content of the page. BeautifulSoup won't retrieve the html content for you, you have to retrieve it yourself. You should pass the content of the page or the file object to `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen(new_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f) # or soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
```

Comment: I do have that part right, I just kinda took snippets from my code. The page loads properly the first time, just not the second. It's a issue that occurs only after the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

if by links you mean urls then you need to use `BeautifulSoup` to make th content readable and parsable to Beautiful soup

if youre just doing the same thing to the new content then just do this

```
import urllib2

def get_data(link):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    return soup
```

now you can use BeautifulSoup to parse the content from the given link you dont need to do it like you had it

more info on beautifulsoup [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
also another helpful site [Bs4 Webscraping](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/beautifulsoup-4-python/)

### EDIT

like you said you already have done that part and you are trying to get the next link by recursion

I wrote this example:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def go_to_next_page(soup, data, curr_link):
    print "Curr Link: " + curr_link 
    pop = soup.find_all('a',{'class':'guide-item yt-uix-sessionlink yt-valign  guide-item-selected'})
    for i in pop:     #These three lines get the new link
        end = i.get('href')

        new_link = 'http://www.youtube.com' + end


    if new_link != "":
        print "Next Link: " + new_link     #then if the new_link isnt empty it gets the new soup
        new_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(new_link).read())
        data = go_to_next_page(new_soup, data, new_link)
    return data

def get_data(link):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    return soup

go_to_next_page(get_data('http://www.youtube.com'),data,'http://www.youtube.com')
```

this example takes a data from the `curr_link` and then finds the new link (which in this example is the Youtube popular page) it then returns the html of the new_links page and recurses with that new data ( im assuming that you are usin the same BeautifulSoup prasing in the function for each time it recurses)

there are probably better ways of doing this but this works fine

Comment: I do have that part right, I just kinda took snippets from my code. The page loads properly the first time, just not the second. It's a issue that occurs only after the recursion.

Comment: so youre using one link to find the next link then using that link as soup??